# Does Response.header override the @Produces annotation?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I'm using Jersey 1.8 and have a situation where `@Produces` annotation is different from `Response.header()`

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response test(){
    return Response.status(200).header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
   .entity("test response");
}
```

Would the response content-type be html or json in this case?

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm sure you could find the answer that way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a small Jax-RS program to verify and it seems that the header set in the `Response` object overrides the `@Produces` annotation.

You can test it with the command line utility `curl` :

```
$ curl -s -i  http://localhost:8080/myapp/myresource/hello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21

Hello World with JSON
```

My WS is similar to your WS :

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public Response helloWorld() {
    return Response.status(200).header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
            .entity("Hello World with JSON").build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitri that's what I was looking for